# SQL query to get the columns into one and comma delimited

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I am getting an output from a query like below -

```
REQUISITION_NUMBER      CANDIDATE_FNAME       CANDIDATE_LNAME       TITLE           EMAIL_ADDRESS       Interviewer Name
12                      John                        Derigour        Hi              fre@stack.com       Maya maraiam
12                      John                        Derigour        Hi              fre@stack.com       Suzie Hero
```

Query -

```
select 
    irc.requistion_number,
    irc.CANDIDATE_FNAME,
    irc.CANDIDATE_LNAME,
    email.title,
    email.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
    email.Interviewer
from 
    irc_requistion irc,
    email_address email
where 
    irc.email_id = email.email_id 
    and irc.requistion_number = email.requistion_number
```

How can I convert this to the following format:

```
REQUISITION_NUMBER      CANDIDATE_FNAME       CANDIDATE_LNAME       TITLE           EMAIL_ADDRESS       Interviewer Name
12                      John                        Derigour        Hi              fre@stack.com       Maya maraiam , Suzie Hero
```

i.e. the interviewer names should come with , in the interviewer name column, rest should remain the same.

Comment: look at LISTAGG function

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged